# Is there a way to display database values based on user input values using HTML form? If yes, how can I do that?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, user-interface

So I am trying to call a value based on user input. I have written the code for the for the form but I need to call the value from the server based on what the user will type on the form.

This is what I have written up until now:

```
@$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$resault = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_");
$rows=$resault->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<pre>',print_r($rows),'</pre>';foreach($rows as $row){
echo $row['field_paint_efficeincy__value'], '<br>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
   Variable: <input type="number" name="P" value="0" /> <br/>
```

Comment: This only works if you *indent* your code properly. Also a `WHERE` clause perhaps.

Comment: That is what have been bothering me, I don't know how to write the WHERE so I can call it from the form, and that is because I am not familiar with mysql from inside php. So how can I call that value?

Comment: `WHERE p = ?` with bound parameters; not as the crude answers advise. Have a look at the manual or http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/275/using-a-database/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries#t=201607281502298987126

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["P"])) {
   $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
   $resault = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_ WHERE field_paint_efficeincy__value = '" . $_GET["P"] . "'");

  //Assuming field_paint_efficeincy__value is the column that should match the input value

   if ($resault->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $resault->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo $row['field_paint_efficeincy__value'] . "<br />";
        }
   }  
   $conn->close();
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="get">
   Variable: <input type="number" name="P" value="0" /> <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton" />
</form>
```

Comment: What if I had to do it with text?I mean yes, I have to change the input from "number" to "text" but the if statement would not work because I am trying to call a number. No?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to use a form submission as a dynamic variable in your query?
If so you need to get the posted value and assign it as a variable to be used in the query. Please remember to sanitize and protect your post submissions.. this is not secure just an example.

```
<?php  
$p = $_POST['P'];
$resault = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM field_data_field_paint_efficeincy_ where p='$p'");
?>
```

Assuming p is the name of the database column.